# Running doctr ml model in docker hangs forever

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, fastapi

I have a fastapi app that loads the doctr model inside the code it just takes an image path and convert it to text

here is the code

```
from doctr.io import DocumentFile
from doctr.models import ocr_predictor
__version__ = "0.1.1"
model = ocr_predictor(pretrained=True)



def process_image(image_path):
    document = DocumentFile.from_images(image_path)
    result = model(document)
    json_response = result.export()
    return json_response
```

I just want to expose the model through an API.

main.py file where my api code set

```
from app.model.model import __version__ as model_version
from app.model.model import process_image
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def home():
    return {"health_check": "OK", "model_version": 'model_version'}
```

When I run the main.py using this code

`uvicorn app.main:app --reload`

everything works

but when I tried to dockerize it it just hangs forever and here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.9

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app/app
```

NOTE: I have an m1 mac

I tried everything to make it works including moving the imports inside the function

```
__version__ = "0.1.1"

def process_image(image_path):
    from doctr.io import DocumentFile
    from doctr.models import ocr_predictor
    model = ocr_predictor(pretrained=True)
    document = DocumentFile.from_images(image_path)
    result = model(document)
    json_response = result.export()
    return json_response
```

but nothing is working when ever the api reaches the imports it just hangs forever and that is only when using docker

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see from your description is that you have mistakenly missed out some necessary libraries inside your requirements.txt. This omission might be causing the problem in the import section of your code, which is leading you into infinite loop. Apart from this, everything is perfect to the best of knowledge.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).